# Sum a list of matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a list of matrices of varying sizes.  How can I quickly sum up all elements in the list of matrices?

This is my current code, but it is pretty slow.  Is there a faster way?

```
  for (i in 1: length(w)) {
    w_sum <- w_sum + sum(apply(w[[i]], 1:2, function (x) x^2))
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matrices are just vectors under the hood, hence you can `unlist`, square and `sum`:

```
sum(unlist(w)^2)
#[1] 2393
```

Using @akrun's example data, gives the same result.

It's much quicker if you've got tonnes of matrices:

```
w <- rep(list(matrix(1:24,nrow=6)), 1e6)
system.time(sum(unlist(w)^2))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.11    0.00    0.10 

system.time(sum(vapply(w, function(x) sum(x^2), numeric(1))))
# user  system elapsed 
# 2.17    0.00    2.17
```

Loops also don't have to be ridiculously slow in this circumstance in comparison:

```
w_sum <- 0
system.time(for(i in seq_along(w)) { w_sum <- w_sum + sum(w[[i]]^2) } )
# user  system elapsed 
# 2.62    0.00    2.62
```

Comment: These were my results, am I missing something?   > system.time(replicate(30000, sum(vapply(w, function(x) sum(x^2), numeric(1)))))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.64    0.38    2.02 
> system.time(replicate(30000, sum(unlist(w)^2)))
   user  system elapsed 
   2.81    0.41    3.22

Comment: @Adam12344 - I can't replicate those results. I get `0.84` seconds for `vapply` and `0.07` seconds for `unlist`